# Link to company page rather than actual company if the company has a company page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

If you go to a job listing for instance, [eharmony](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102612/senior-software-engineer-core-services-eharmony?searchTerm=eharmony&offset=0&ajax=1), you have this:

[image]

I think that link to eHarmony should actually take you to the company page instead of eHarmony's career page.  Reason being is the eHarmony company page already has this link.  So it should of taken you here: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/eharmony and in this case there is a link to the careers page:

[image]

While a company like [Palantir](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104861/software-engineer-palantir?offset=5&sort=s&pg=1&searchTerm=engineer) who doesn't have a company page can then link you to their page from their job listing as it currently does.

I ask this because I think we are not giving the company page some love (or even a chance here) we go directly to the company careers page, where I would think someone on so jobs really wanted to go to the company page and from here they can be redirected to the eHarmony site.

Comment: Would be nice to differentiate between these links if this was done. Expecting an internal link and getting an off-site one can be jarring.

Comment: @Shog9 - That is exactly what happened to me.  After I saw the link I thought by clicking on it I'd get it's company page because I wanted to see info about this company before I even go to the company site.  I don't think we are giving company pages enough credit, those pages are awesome.

Comment: The usual method of dealing with this kind of thing would be to use an icon to indicate the link navigates to an external url. Something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/8u6r0Mr.png)

Comment: @rossipedia - That's fine and I notice you guys do that a lot but I simply think the actual link on the job listing should really go to the company page first.  The company page being that it is the COMPANY PAGE will then link to the actual company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just implemented this and pushed to production. Thanks for the feedback!